# Python - how to make a BoolProperty local?

Tags: python, scripting

I need subtabs. I have several settings and elements to hide. So i made me a BoolProperty and two subtabs with it. The problem is, this BoolProperty is global. Means when i open one subtab, then the other subtab opens too.

My problem is that i have more than one panel where this subtab could be. Think of the background images tabs in the properties sidebar where you can have more than one panel. One for every new background image. Now think that you have a subtab at each of them. And then all of them opens when you click at one of it. That's the kind of problem that i have at the moment.

Is there a way to make the BoolProperty local? So that just one subtab opens when i click at it?

I want the subtab BoolProperty to be unique per instance. Something that can be reused where ever you need it in the UI. A good example is again the Background Images tab where you can close every panel individually.

Code:

```
import bpy

class MyData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    subtab_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="A checkbox", description="Do this or that", default = False) # Our prop

class SubtabProp(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Subtab prop"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene # Our data is in the current scene

        if not scene.my_addon_data.subtab_bool:
            layout.prop(scene.my_addon_data,"subtab_bool", emboss=False, icon="TRIA_RIGHT", text="- Settings -")

        else:
            layout.prop(scene.my_addon_data,"subtab_bool", emboss=False, icon="TRIA_DOWN", text="+ Settings +")

            layout.operator("mesh.primitive_plane_add", text="Plane", icon='MESH_PLANE')

        if not scene.my_addon_data.subtab_bool:
            layout.prop(scene.my_addon_data,"subtab_bool", emboss=False, icon="TRIA_RIGHT", text="- Othersettings -")

        else:
            layout.prop(scene.my_addon_data,"subtab_bool", emboss=False, icon="TRIA_DOWN", text="+ Othersettings +")

            layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="Cube", icon='MESH_CUBE')


# ---------------------------- register 

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SubtabProp)
    #Our data block
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyData) # Our data block
    bpy.types.Scene.my_addon_data = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData) # Bind reference of type of our data block to type Scene objects

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_addon_data # Unregister our data block when unregister.
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyData) # Our data block
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SubtabProp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. I want the subtab boolproperty to be unique per instance. Something that can be reused where ever you need it in the ui. Editing the question once more ...

Comment: I fear i miss the skills to describe the problem more clear than how it already is described. Even more because my mother tongue is not english. I basically want to work with a local variable instead of a global one. Something that should work in any language. Thus my confusion here.

Comment: @zeffi, i have understood that it doesn't work that way with a BoolProperty. What i search for now is the substitute. A solution that can have different local states. But yes, maybe i really run into a Blender Python limit here, and the problem is unsolveable. Nevertheless thanks for your patience and help :)

Comment: Within the one panel you will need multiple BoolProperties (And you should update your snippet to reflect that you understand that)..and then we can move on to another problem . namely, finding a convenient way to register a PropertyGroup/Collection per visible 3dView (to get the same effect as the BackgroundImages tab you mention)

Comment: @zeffi, i don't understand. How could i update my snippet with the solution that i ask for? For that i would need the solution ...